# Allow user to edit only his own articles

Tags: angularjs

I want to know the most correct way for controlling access to the resources of an angular application.

To control the access to the edition component and the addition component of an article I use the method canActivate of the guard, and i check if a token exists to authorize access or redirect the user to login page if the token don't exist...

Now to allow user to edit only his own articles, I should check if the the id of the author of the article is equal to authenticate user... And If it's not his own article I want to redirect user to a page that show him that he is not authorised to edit the article...

So I should make this test at the guard or at the typescript of the edition component.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canActivate guard is a good solution for yes/no access to a page (e.g. check token), and you should include an extra one for edit routes (e.g. is current user author of article).

If you put the logic for checking if user can edit articcles in a service, then include the service on your component, you can easily check, for example:

```
<div class="edit-article" *ngIf="canEditArticle()"><a href="...">Edit</a></div>
```

Then in your component:

```
canEditArticle() {
   return authService.canEditArticle();
}
```

You will also want to make sure you have the business logic on your application server (or persistence layer).